# Link a set of radio buttons to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, slider

first of all: I'm a newbie when it comes to JS/jQuery - so please be gentle^^

Here my Question:

I have a set of customized(styled) radio buttons (currently 10) and 2 divs with a left/right arrow background-image. Both divs set the "left" value of a so called "Slider" per function to move the div to left and right.
So - I want to have the functionality that when I click the left/right arrow that a radio button will move it's active state to the next radio button. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your code segment.

Comment: create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Okay, I need some time to downgrade the code segment, please wait ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/7xe9g/

```
$("#left").click(function () {
  cur--;
  if (cur < 1) { cur = 6;}
  $("#r" + cur).prop("checked", true)
});
```

The code could use a little cleaning up (merging the two functions, etc)… but it gets the point across of how you can change the selected radio button left and right.

Comment: ^ this! Thank you very much Dan for your help!
Let me test this for my situation...=)

Comment: allright, I got it to work but needed some other code, since I implemented a jquery plugin to format my checkboxes/radios